# Do I need to kill Railroaders when playing for Institute? How to avoid killing them?

Tags: fallout-4

I play for Institute and there is a quest "End of the Line" where the Institute wants me to kill Railroaders.

There is a video where someone avoids killing them, but there is a lot of information missing how to reproduce it, I am unable to do it:

The quest is also not well documented on Fallout wiki: 
http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/End_of_the_Line

So is it possible to avoid killing the Railroaders and what are the steps to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**If you want to complete the Institute storyline in the unmodded version of Fallout 4, you must turn on the Railroad.** Once you get [*End of the Line*](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/End_of_the_Line), the quest will only resolve if you take one of two actions:

- Kill Desdemona. This makes the Railroad hostile toward you.
- Warn Desdemona. This keeps the Railroad friendly and allows you to progress through their quests, up through [*Rockets Red Glare*](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Rockets%27_Red_Glare). At this point, you'll receive the quest [*The Nuclear Option*](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/The_Nuclear_Option_(Railroad)) from the Railroad, where they ask you to attack the Institute. This forces you to choose which group to attack to progress further in the story.

Comment: And what does that choice from the video mean? It's modded game or it's temporary and I need to decide after that anyway?

Comment: @Salda In the video, the player is warning Desdemona. Per my answer, this keeps both the Railroad and the Institute friendly for a little longer, but you'll eventually have to decide to attack either the Railroad or the Institute.